# DC voltage stepping down but keeping current uchanged with no regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

Is there any way to divide DC voltage or stepping it down but keeping the current peak unchanged? But I can't use a voltage regulator. In fact, I want to make a regulator 5V output into 4.5 ~ 4.7 V but keeping the current peak same. Current is now 1.7 ~ 2A.

Comment: What does "keeping the current constant" mean?

Comment: Simply adding a large Schottky diode in series with the power supply will drop the required 3V. Given that the requirement doesn't seem to be a hard ceiling, you might also be able to achieve it with a power resistor or simply long coil of wire in the power supply.

Comment: @pjc50 Hi. I have FR207, FR107, 1N5399, 1N5408,1N4007, 4148. Do you think any of these diodes can be helpful?

Comment: Never mind. I just figured 1N4007 has a 1V forward voltage drop. So, this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that when you say...

> keeping the current constant

...you mean keep the peak current capability of the reduced-voltage supply as it were before at 2A max.

Without a regulator (of the conventional type) you are probably stuck with using a zener diode and feed resistor. The regular 5 volts needs to drop to 4.7 volts so choose a zener diode of 4.7 volt rating. The current draw (before the zener stops operating at its knee point) is 2 A and this dictates the series resistor between 5V and zener: -

R = \$\dfrac{5V - 4.7V}{2A}\$ = 0.15 ohms with a dissipation of 0.6 watts (choose a 1 watt resistor).

The zener, on the lightest loads, will be consuming the most power and this will be Vz * 2A = 9.4 watts. Best choose something like a 12 watt or 15 watt device.

That's how to do it without a regulator and it's an ugly power hungry solution but will work.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed it would be some semiconductor way. I assumed it will require transistors. Anyway, Thanks for the help.